# "Error reading variable: Cannot access memory at address" in GDB

Tags: c++, segmentation-fault

Every time I run the below program, I get a Segmentation Fault with the error "error reading variable: Cannot access memory at address". I'm new to C++, so I'm not really sure what I'm doing wrong here. I've added asterisks to the specific line in my code that causes the error.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <sstream>

using namespace std;

double sqrt(double eps, double num, double last_guess)
{

    if(num == 0 || num == 1)
    {
        return num;
    }

    double next = (num + (num/last_guess)) / 2;

    if(labs(last_guess - next) <= eps)
        return next;
    else
        return sqrt(eps, num, next);
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    double eps, num;
    istringstream iss; //input string

    if(argc == 3)
    {
        iss.str(argv[1]);
        if ( !(iss >> eps) ) {
            cerr << "Error: The first argument is not a valid double." << endl;
            return 1;
        }

        iss.clear();

        iss.str(argv[2]);
        if ( !(iss >> num) ) {
            cerr << "Error: The second argument is not a valid double." << endl;
            return 1;
        }

        iss.clear();

    ***} else if(argc == 2) {***
        iss.str(argv[1]);
        if ( !(iss >> num) ) {
            cerr << "Error: Argument is not a valid double." << endl;
            return 1;
        }

        eps = 0.000001;
    }

    cout << "sqrt(" << eps << ", " << num << ") = " << sqrt(eps,num, num) << endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Test input: 0.000001 4.0

Comment: What are your inputs? You've probably got a stack overflow due to too many recursions inside `sqrt`

Comment: Does this answer your question? [SegFault error when computing square root (Newton's method)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59958672/segfault-error-when-computing-square-root-newtons-method)   Same code same poster.

Comment: @RichardCritten No, it doesn't, but I've just found the specific line that causes the SegFault.

Comment: @AlanBirtles I updated the post with my test input.

Comment: @DrewDormann When argc==2, I set eps to be 0.000001. You're right, I do not consider the case where argc==1 (no input), but I always test with input.

Comment: @TheFiveHundredYears its not useful to ask the same question twice, if your first question isn't getting any answers edit it to be more specific don't just ask again